# Submitting a form with SQLAlchemy throws 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am new both to Flask and SQLAlchemy and to coding, so have patience please.

What I am trying to do is to send data through a form to my database.
Worked fine until I wanted two more tables with relationship one to many, as in a *plant can accumulate many elements and a plant can have many properties* and flask throws error ***AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'***.
The form is :

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import  QuerySelectMultipleField
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField,BooleanField, TextAreaField

#Query for Dynamic Nutrient Accumulator Model
def enabled_dna():
    return DNA.query.all()
#Query for Nitrogen Fixers Nursing Model

def enabled_nfn():
    return NFN.query.all()

class NewPlantForm(FlaskForm):
    common_name = StringField('Common Name', render_kw={"placeholder": "Common name"},
                          validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=40)])
    botanical_name = StringField('Botanical Name', render_kw={"placeholder": "Botanical name"},
                             validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=80)])
    short_description = TextAreaField('Short Description', render_kw={"placeholder": "Please add a short description"},
                                  validators=[DataRequired()])
    medicinal = TextAreaField('Medicinal Use', render_kw={"placeholder": "Medicinal use"},
                        validators=[DataRequired()])
    dna = QuerySelectMultipleField('Select Element',query_factory=enabled_dna,allow_blank=True)
    nfn = QuerySelectMultipleField('Select Property',query_factory=enabled_nfn,allow_blank=True)
    submit = SubmitField('Add plant')
```

The models.py looks like this :

```
#Plants Table
class Plants(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    common_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    botanical_name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    short_description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    medicinal = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), default='default_plant_pic.jpg')
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    dna_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('DNA.id'))
    dna = db.relationship('DNA', backref=db.backref('plant_dna', lazy='dynamic'))  # Dynamic_Nutrient_Accumulated
    nfn_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('NFN.id'))
    nfn = db.relationship('NFN', backref=db.backref('plant_nfn', lazy='dynamic'))  # Nitrogen_Fixers_Nursing

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Plants('{self.common_name}', '{self.botanical_name}', '{self.short_description}'," \
        f" '{self.medicinal}', '{self.dna}', '{self.nfn}' )"

#Dynamic_Nutrient_Accumulated
class DNA(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    element = db.Column(db.String(15))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[ {}]'.format(self.element)
#Nitrogen_Fixers_Nursing
class NFN(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    plant_extra = db.Column(db.String(40))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[ {}]'.format(self.plant_extra)
```

The route and form worked fine with the form containing fields only for one table. However, it doesn't work now while I added second and third fields containing data from other tables(form.dna.data and form.nfn.data).

My route for New Plant is :

```
@app.route("/plants/new/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required# User must be logged in to create a new plant
def new_plant():
    form = NewPlantForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_plant = Plants(common_name=form.common_name.data,
                           botanical_name=form.botanical_name.data,
                           short_description=form.short_description.data,
                           medicinal=form.medicinal.data,
                           dna=form.dna.data,
                           nfn=form.nfn.data,
                           author=current_user)
        db.session.add(new_plant)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Thank you ! You have successfully added a plant '
              'to the database!', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('plants'))
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='img/plants/default_plant_pic.jpg')

    return render_template('new_plant.html', title='Add new plant',
                       image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

And route where to render the information of plants is :

```
@app.route("/plants")
def plants():
    plants = Plants.query.all()
    return render_template('plants.html', title= 'Plants Database', plants=plants)
```

I have tried working with this locally from terminal and it works, but I don't know what I'm missing or if the relationship model is wrong to get it working from the flask app.

Thanks in advance for patience and help.

### Update

After trial and error, it now seems to work all of it (add a plant with the selected fields to the DB, render the plant data correctly into the template, the plant is added correctly to the DB-viewing with DB Browser for SQLite) after I've changed *QuerySelectMultipleField* to *QuerySelectField*. However, my point was to be able to select and render multiple choices.

Another thing that I have noticed is that when using ***QuerySelectField***, the template renders correctly a dropdown, but when trying to use ***QuerySelectMultipleField***, it renders  just a list with elements, no dropdown.

Here is the small part of the template with the select field **form.dna** and **form.nfn**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ form.dna(class="form-control form-control-sm") }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      {{ form.nfn(class="form-control form-control-sm")}}
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap. Could this thing be related to the template formatting not correctly wrote for the multiple select? 
Thanks.

### Update2

I managed to get ***QuerySelectMultipleField*** to work by looping through the form data like this :

```
 @app.route("/plants/new/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 @login_required# User must be logged in to create a new plant
 def new_plant():
     form = NewPlantForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
       new_plant = Plants(common_name = form.common_name.data, botanical_name = form.botanical_name.data,
                       short_description = form.short_description.data, medicinal=form.medicinal.data,
                       author=current_user)
      **for dna_element in form.dna.data:
          new_plant.dna = dna_element
      for nfn_element in form.nfn.data:
          new_plant.nfn = nfn_element**

    db.session.add(new_plant)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(f'Thank you ! You have successfully added a plant to the database!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('plants'))
image_file = url_for('static', filename='img/plants/default_plant_pic.jpg')
return render_template('new_plant.html', title='Add new plant',
                       image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

I don't get anymore the error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'**  and the plant is successful added to the database,  however when I'm looking in the database, I can see that only one option was selected, not multiple choices.
From what I've read here : [Flask App Using WTForms with SelectMultipleField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558345/flask-app-using-wtforms-with-selectmultiplefield) , I was supposed to use *form.something.data* to get a list of items which I did, but still doesn't work and I only get one item.
Please help. 
Thanks !

### Update 3 and solving the problem

After implementing **sleblanc's** response, I now have the following code that works with the form and displays correctly: 
**models.py : **

```
plants_dna_table = db.Table(
'plants_dna',
db.Column('plants_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plants.id'), nullable=False),
db.Column('dna_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('DNA.id'), nullable=False),
db.UniqueConstraint('plants_id', 'dna_id'))

plants_nfn_table = db.Table(
'plants_nfn',
db.Column('plants_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plants.id'), nullable=False),
db.Column('nfn_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('NFN.id'), nullable=False),
db.UniqueConstraint('plants_id', 'nfn_id'))

#Plants Table
class Plants(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
common_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
botanical_name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
short_description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
medicinal = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), default='default_plant_pic.jpg')
date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
dna = db.relationship('DNA', secondary = plants_dna_table)  # Dynamic_Nutrient_Accumulated
nfn = db.relationship('NFN', secondary = plants_nfn_table)  # Nitrogen_Fixers_Nursing

def __repr__(self):
    return f"Plants('{self.common_name}', '{self.botanical_name}', '{self.short_description}'," \
        f" '{self.medicinal}', '{self.dna}', '{self.nfn}' )"

#Dynamic_Nutrient_Accumulated
class DNA(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   element = db.Column(db.String(15))

   def __repr__(self):
       return '{}'.format(self.element)
#Nitrogen_Fixers_Nursing
class NFN(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   plant_extra = db.Column(db.String(40))

   def __repr__(self):
   return '{}'.format(self.plant_extra)
```

The **db.ForeignKey('DNA.id')** displayed with capital letters does the job and will not get the error for not finding the table DNA.

**routes.py : **

```
#Route for users to add a plant to the database
@app.route("/plants/new/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required# User must be logged in to create a new plant
def new_plant():
form = NewPlantForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    new_plant = Plants(common_name = form.common_name.data, botanical_name = form.botanical_name.data,
                       short_description = form.short_description.data, medicinal=form.medicinal.data,
                       author=current_user)
    for dna_element in form.dna.data:
        new_plant.dna.append(dna_element)

    for nfn_element in form.nfn.data:
        new_plant.nfn.append(nfn_element)

    print(new_plant)
    db.session.add(new_plant)
    db.session.commit()
    flash(f'Thank you ! You have successfully added a plant to the database!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('plants'))
image_file = url_for('static', filename='img/plants/default_plant_pic.jpg')
return render_template('new_plant.html', title='Add new plant',
                       image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

Thanks @sleblanc!

Comment: not 100% sure but I think you need to get rid of the `.all()` in `enabled_dna` and `enabled_nfn` for the `QuerySelectMultipleField`

Comment: as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887519/how-to-use-queryselectfield-in-flask

Comment: thanks for reply  I have tried also that, but to no avail. I have read also about the relationships, so either the models I have wrote are wrong or the route logic, or both , but testing in cmd they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have modeled your relationships in reverse.

You have a One-To-Many relationship from your Plants to your DNA and NFN if I am not mistaken, meaning that one 'Plants' object will have several DNA, and several NFN. As defined, your 'Plants' model only has a single field for DNA and a single field for NFN, meaning that there is no way to store the association in the database.

You will need to modify your Plants model to represent the relationship. You must first determine if a 'DNA' or a 'NFN' can be shared by multiple 'Plants', or if they are unique for each 'Plants' instance, as it involves a different schema.

```
class Plants(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...

# second option, exclusive relationship
class DNA(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    plants_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Plants.id), nullable=False)
    ...

class NFN(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    plants_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Plants.id), nullable=False)
    ...


# first option, non-exclusive relationship
class Plants(db.Model):
    ...
    dna = relationship("DNA", secondary=plants_dna_table)
    nfn = relationship("NFN", secondary=plants_nfn_table) 


plants_dna_table = db.Table(
    'plants_dna',
    db.Column('plants_id', db.ForeignKey('plants.id'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('dna_id', db.ForeignKey('dna.id'), nullable=False),
    db.UniqueConstraint('plants_id', 'dna_id'),
    )

plants_nfn_table = db.Table(
    'plants_nfn',
    db.Column('plants_id', db.ForeignKey('plants.id'), nullable=False),
    db.Column('nfn_id', db.ForeignKey('nfn.id'), nullable=False),
    db.UniqueConstraint('plants_id', 'nfn_id'),
    )
```

After having modified the Plants model and setup a relationship between the two, keep in mind that the .dna and .nfn attributes will have a list type. You can add a relationship to the instances by `append`ing to the list.

I highly recommend you use FlaskForm.populate_obj:

```
@app.route("/plants/new/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required# User must be logged in to create a new plant
def new_plant():
obj = Plants()
form = NewPlantForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.populate_obj(obj)

    print(obj) # debugging
    db.session.add(obj)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Thank you ! You have successfully added '
          'a plant to the database!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('plants'))

image_file = url_for('static', filename='img/plants/default_plant_pic.jpg')
return render_template('new_plant.html', title='Add new plant',
                   image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

Also, it lets you combine a future Plant update view by adding just a few more lines:

```
@app.route('/plant/<id>/edit', methods=('GET', 'POST',))
@app.route('/plant/new', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create_plant(id=None):
    if id is not None:
        obj = Plant.query.get(id)
    else:
        obj = Plant()

    form = PlantForm(request.form, obj=obj)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(obj)

        db.session.add(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Thank you ! You have successfully added '
              'a plant to the database!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('get_plant', id=obj.id))

    else:
        image_file = url_for(
            'static', 
            filename='img/plants/default_plant_pic.jpg')
        return render_template('plant.html', title='Add new plant',
                               image_file=image_file,
                               form=form, obj=obj)
```

Comment: If you are new to data modeling, the concept explained in this answer is called an "association table" https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

Comment: Hi, sleblanc and thank you for your help. I was thinking that something was wrong with the models. I have used the non-exclusive relationship as you said, but when trying to add to the db the plant.dna.append(element) , I got this wierd error now :** _state = attributes.instance_state(instance)
AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' ; sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.orm.collections.InstrumentedList' is not mapped**

Comment: I'm not sure if that will fix all your problems, but note that you cannot just take your form values and append them to the .dna or .nfn relationships as those are expecting DNA and NFN objects, not text (form) data. In this loop, you may query your database to get the DNA or NFN objects if they exist already, otherwise you will create a new instance and add it to the session.

Comment: sleblanc it works ! OMG, finally works. I have tested it on the CMD and also it works and displays correctly after user submits the form. Many, many thanks !!! I now know how to implement it in the future correctly. The error above was because I was doing db.session.add(plant.dna), instead of db.session.add(plant). However, I added the relationships table above the Model Plants and have added db.Integer to that. I was trying before with the table relationship, but implemented in it both table DNA and NFN, not separate. Thank you !

Comment: Welcome! The session is smart enough to add dependents when you add a 'parent' object, so just doing session.add(plant) does not require you to also do `session.add_all(plant.dna); ...`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have forgotten that thing, but learned alot these two weeks with trial and error and specially with your response now.

Comment: Thank you for the extra information regarding FlaskForm.populate_obj. Will sure use it to update plants in the future !